# Debian : RAID drive showing 62% disk already used even though lot remaining

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, debian, raid

Sometime back I had configured RAID0 on our Debian X64 server and so far, it is working fine, no issues. One day, I just checked `df -h`, and it shows me that 62% of disk-space is already used.

The RAID is configured with two 2TB drives, and currently only 20GB is used, but when I see the output, it says, the size if 34G. Is something wrong with my setup?

output of df -H :

```
df -H
Filesystem                                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                                                  456G  7,3G  425G   2% /
udev                                                     11M     0   11M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                   3,4G  300k  3,4G   1% /run
/dev/disk/by-uuid/ae73679c-c3cd-4a60-bcbb-5b6ddce867f7  456G  7,3G  425G   2% /
tmpfs                                                   5,3M     0  5,3M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                    11G  4,1k   11G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sdc2                                               529M   41M  461M   9% /boot
// This last one   
 /dev/md1                                                 34G   20G   13G  62% /media/attachment
```

output of mdadm --detail /dev/md1 :

```
/dev/md1:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Wed Apr 29 11:12:21 2015
     Raid Level : raid0
     Array Size : 33553408 (32.00 GiB 34.36 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Wed Apr 29 11:12:21 2015
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

     Chunk Size : 512K

           Name : legion03:1  (local to host legion03)
           UUID : 68e853a6:7af46176:d9c147c7:6ff87bb0
         Events : 0

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
```

Output of

```
fdisk -l | grep Disk

fdisk -l | grep Disk
Disk /dev/md1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00089ca4
Disk /dev/sdc: 480.1 GB, 480103981056 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00047ef7
Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000275d2
Disk /dev/md1: 34.4 GB, 34358689792 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

Is there something wrong with my RAID0 setup? Any help would be nice. Thank you.

*Update*

Output of fdisk -l :

```
fdisk -l 

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
81 heads, 63 sectors/track, 765633 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00089ca4

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048  3907029167  1953513560   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdc: 480.1 GB, 480103981056 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 58369 cylinders, total 937703088 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00047ef7

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            2048    33556480    16777216+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdc2        33558528    34607104      524288+  83  Linux
/dev/sdc3        34609152   937701040   451545944+  83  Linux

Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
81 heads, 63 sectors/track, 765633 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000275d2

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048  3907029167  1953513560   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/md1: 34.4 GB, 34358689792 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 8388352 cylinders, total 67106816 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 1048576 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Comment: Is there something in Recycle Bin or does the OS keep previous versions of the files?

Comment: What is the output of `fdisk -l`?

Comment: Proper process to request a migration is to flag it. That said, this is entirely on topic here, and It dosen't quite feel like an SF question. Its very likely it'll get bounced back here.

Comment: @MichaelHampton : I have added the output. I think as I have to create a new Raid setup with the two 2Tb drives, I would like to make them Raid1, instead of Raid0.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek : Thank you. I will let the question stay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `/dev/md1` appears to be a combination of two partitions, each 16 GiB in size (or possibly different sizes which add up to 32 GiB). Output from `fdisk -l` added afterward contradicts that. Without a complete history we can only speculate what led to the present condition of `/dev/md1`, but one possibility is that the partition tables changed after the RAID device was created (I haven't tested whether that sequence of events can lead to this condition).

To report just the partition tables on those two disks, use a command like this:

```
fdisk -l /dev/sd[ab]
```

If you want to keep the 20G of data in that partition, you'll need to copy it elsewhere before recreating `/dev/md1`.

The present partition tables on `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` are appropriate for a RAID partition on those disks. I edited out my earlier commentary on how (and whether) to partition those disks.

To dismantle and recreate `/dev/md1` you can use this command sequence:

```
mdadm --stop /dev/md1
mdadm --create /dev/md1 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sd[ab]1
```

I believe that first command is non-destructive, but you'll want to have the existing data in `/dev/md1` backed up before you run the second one (and, really, before you run the first one). I believe `mdadm --assemble` would allow you to reverse the effect of that first command, but that's unnecessary once your data is backed up.

I haven't tested this sequence of commands (not recently anyway) but it's consistent with my recollection, and my reading of the documentation. Be careful to type the device names correctly. It will be interesting to find out whether `mdadm --create` uses the full partition size of the two component disks when creating the RAID mirror. Your comment indicated you want a RAID mirror; the parameter value for `--level` would be different if you wanted something else.

You might also want to check the contents of `/etc/mdadm.conf` or `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` to make sure they are not specifying undesired default values.

Comment: So, the RAID setup currently I have is incorrect, right? As you may have noticed that I have Raid0, but would like to convert it to Raid1. I have space on my 512Gb SSD to take a backup of the 34 GB drive and then begin the operation. As I would be creating a new Raid setup by formatting the two 2TB drives, can you tell me how I can make it to Raid1 by adding both the drives to that Raid. Thank you.

Comment: My explanation is not consistent with the `fdisk -l` output added afterward.  It's not clear how `/dev/md1` was created, but once the data is backed up it should be straightforward to recreate it. I'll edit the answer to explain that.

Comment: Yes, I had to wipe both the 2TB drives after taking a backup, and recreate the RAID-array with the command you mentioned. And finally export the the current RAID config to over-ride the old one. Thank you. :-)